# Can I change a rule of another element inside the rules of another element in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the opacity of other img's when one image is hovered over. Can I do that?

```
.layers-animation img:nth-child(4):hover {
    transform: translate(180px, -200px);
    transition: 0.5s;

    /* I want to be able to do this V */

    .layers-animation img {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    /* (Change the opacity of all the other images when this image is hovered over.) */

}
```

Is there any way to do this in CSS3?

Comment: You can't select (hence style) previous siblings or parents with CSS. You'll need JavaScript for it. CSS parses forwards, never backwards.

Comment: Andrei is correct-- unfortunately, the restriction that prevents selection of previous elements (including previous siblings) will be the limiting factor.  The only way you could feasibly pull this off would be if you were to leverage the `:hover` pseudo on both the parent and the target.

Comment: @KalpeshShende There is no parent selector.

Comment: @jhpratt  ya .. we cannot select parent i didnt rememeber what I did last time thus wrote it by mistake sorry for that.Thank you for pointing it out.... Anyways I have answered below please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

https://codepen.io/kalpeshshende/pen/JmZeyK

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .main{
            height: 300px;width: 300px;
            background: red;display: grid;
            grid-gap: 10px;
            padding: 10px;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        }
        .main:hover > div{
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        .subMain{
            background: yellow;
        }
        .main:hover > div:hover{
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="subMain">1</div>
        <div class="subMain">2</div>
        <div class="subMain">3</div>
        <div class="subMain">4</div>
        <div class="subMain">5</div>
        <div class="subMain">6</div>
        <div class="subMain">7</div>
        <div class="subMain">8</div>
        <div class="subMain">9</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation of what you did and why? As it is right now, I see zero relation between this and OP's code.

Comment: I didnt go with the code as the result was impossible with that code. As per the question asked, the one who posted wanted to make the division hovered opaque and other semi transparent. This result can be achieved with this code and not with that one.. I guess anything that helps is fine. !!

Comment: @jhpratt: This appears to be the technique that takes advantage of :hover being applied to ancestors of a :hover descendant to apply different styles to it and its :not(:hover) siblings. It's a pretty common technique, one that only works with :hover. It is by no means a previous sibling selector, and it does have a fatal flaw in that any .main:hover rule kicks in when any part of .main is hovered, including itself, or the other descendants.

Answer (score 0):

in CSS you can select the single sibling that comes after your elements with `+`, and all the siblings that come after your element with `~`

so if you have two images

```
<img class="img-one>
<img class="img-two>
```

you do this

```
.img-one:hover + .img-two {
 * your css rules here *
}
```

this doesn't work in those cases:

- if you're trying to select a previous element
- if the two elements are nested and are not direct siblings

that's because of how css works, you can only control what comes after your css element, what was rendered before can't be altered.